# HTML Sub Submenu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

I want to create a Menu Bar on a website with sub submenus. I am not able to fix the following problems: 
1. The sub submenu items appear in the same box as the submenu items
2. the sub submenu items are always taking space even though they are invisible
3. the sub submenu items show when you hover the submenu box but they should only show up when you hover the menu item they belong to.

Unfortunately I have to use an online tool that defines the menu the way it is written in the code below. (menulevel1 and menulevel2)

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li class="menulevel1"><a class="" href="#>Timetable</a></li>
<li class="menulevel1"><a class="" href="#">Subjects</a></li>
<li class="menulevel2"><a class="" href="#">Chemistry</a></li>
<li class="menulevel2"><a class="" href="#">Maths</a></li>
<li class="menulevel2"><a class="" href="#">PE</a></li>
<li class="menulevel1"><a class="" href="#">Food</a></li>
<li class="menulevel1"><a class="" href="#">Drinks</a></li>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. 
I really appreciate your help.

Code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/TheBB23/q6gncy07/

```
enter code here
```

Thank you

Comment: If you can refactor the html code you can do it this way: https://jsfiddle.net/dp3vh67y/1/ , if you can't, you can access to `.dropdown-menu`via javascript and wrap the `.menulevel2` items with a ul, so you can style their container.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to edit the HTML code because I am running a tool on the website that generates the HTML responsible for the part of the HTML code showcased above.
Is there an option to do it without changing the HTML but adding some Javascript or CSS?

Answer (score 0):

nest menu level 2 inside of the subject li.

```
    `<li class="menulevel1"><a class="" href="#">Subjects</a>
    <ul>
    <li class="menulevel2"><a class="" href="#">Chemistry</a></li>
    <li class="menulevel2"><a class="" href="#">Maths</a></li>
    <li class="menulevel2"><a class="" href="#">PE</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>`
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to edit the HTML code because I am running a tool on the website that generates the HTML responsible for the part of the HTML code showcased above. Is there an option to do it without changing the HTML but adding some Javascript or CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Close menu1 in a  tag of its own and same for menu2. Don't forget to close each tags.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to edit the HTML code because I am running a tool on the website that generates the HTML responsible for the part of the HTML code showcased above. Is there an option to do it without changing the HTML but adding some Javascript or CSS?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
        <li>
            <a href="">Birds</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Ratites</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Fowl</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Neoaves</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Mammals</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Monotremes</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Marsupials</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Placentals</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Reptiles</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Lizards and snakes</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Tortoises and turtles</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Crocodilians</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Tuatara</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Amphibians</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Frogs and toads</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Salamanders and newts</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Caecilians</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Apply CSS on this and you are good to go

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I am not able to edit the HTML code because I am running a tool on the website that generates the HTML responsible for the part of the HTML code showcased above. Is there an option to do it without changing the HTML but adding some Javascript or CSS?